How to fix my Python Flet Audio Visualizer that is not working without an error in the terminal
Title: Audio Plays but Spectrum Visualization Not Showing in Flet Audio Visualizer.
I am working on an Audio Visualizer using the Flet framework. The sound plays correctly, but the spectrum visualization does not show up.
Here is my code:

import flet as ft
import numpy as np
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import threading
import pygame
import queue

# Audio settings
sample_rate = 44100
chunk_size = 1024

class AudioVisualizer(ft.Container):
    def __init__(self, file_path: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.image = ft.Image(src=io.BytesIO(), width=800, height=400)
        self.page = None
        self.audio_data = self.load_audio()
        self.audio_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.start_visualization()

    def load_audio(self):
        audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(self.file_path)
        audio = audio.set_frame_rate(sample_rate)
        audio_data = np.array(audio.get_array_of_samples())
        audio_data = audio_data / np.max(np.abs(audio_data))  # Normalize
        return audio_data

    def update_visualization(self, audio_data):
        try:
            plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
            plt.plot(audio_data)
            plt.ylim(-1, 1)
            plt.gca().set_facecolor('white')  
            buf = io.BytesIO()
            plt.savefig(buf, format='png', facecolor='white')  # Set figure background to white
            buf.seek(0)
            self.image.src = buf
            if self.page:
                self.page.update()  # Update the Flet image control
            else:
                print("Page reference is not set.")
            plt.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in update_visualization: {e}")

    def start_visualization(self):
        try:
            self.visualization_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.visualize_audio, daemon=True)
            self.visualization_thread.start()
            print("Visualization thread started.")
            self.play_audio()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in start_visualization: {e}")

    def visualize_audio(self):
        chunks = make_chunks(self.audio_data, chunk_size)
        for chunk in chunks:
            self.audio_queue.put(chunk)
        self.audio_queue.put(None)  # Signal to stop the update loop

    def play_audio(self):
        try:
            pygame.mixer.init()
            pygame.mixer.music.load(self.file_path)
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            print("Audio playback started.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in play_audio: {e}")

    def update_loop(self):
        try:
            while True:
                audio_data = self.audio_queue.get()
                if audio_data is None:
                    break
                self.update_visualization(audio_data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in update_loop: {e}")

def main(page: ft.Page) -> None:
    try:
        audio_file_path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\your_music_file.mp3"
        visualizer = AudioVisualizer(audio_file_path)
        
        visualizer.page = page

        # Add controls to the page
        page.add(
            ft.Container(
                content=visualizer.image,
                alignment=ft.alignment.center,
                expand=True,
            )
        )
        page.update()
        print("Page updated with visualizer.")
        
        # Start the update loop in the main thread
        visualizer.update_loop()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in main: {e}")

ft.app(target=main)

I’ve tried everything I could think of, but I can't get the spectrum visualization to appear. The audio plays without any issue, and there are no errors in the terminal.
What I’ve checked/tried:
Verified that the audio data is being loaded and normalized correctly.
Confirmed that the update_visualization method is being called with the audio data chunks.
Ensured that the pygame.mixer is properly initialized and the audio is playing.

Question:
Why is the spectrum visualization not showing, and how can I fix it?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

i don't think matplotlib is responsive enough to act as a realtime spectrum visualizer

Is there an alternative that can help me?
